# Active remainder with interval between Create Date and Due Date

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-foundation, designer-workflow

How to make workflow or action workflow which can find date/interval between Create Date and Due Date and send notification every day till Due Date?

I will be very garteful for help.

Best regards,

Comment: I have the same question as well that I posted today. You might want to test out the SP Designer action called "Find Interval Between Dates" if you have 2010, although it wasn't working for me. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/62389/designer-workflow-find-interval-between-dates-action-not-working